# How to modify image.OnClick in share layout.cshtml from another view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have declare an image in _Layout.cshtml inside the Shared folder.

```
    <img src="~Content/icons/btnBack.png onclick="ImageClick"/>
```

I would like to navigate to different page base on the javascript function trigger from different view. For example, when I clicked the btnBack.png in history.cshtml, I want it to redirect to home.cshtml. When I clicked the btnBack.png in historyDetails.cshtml, I want it to redirect to history.cshtml. How can I achieve that? Should I put the javascript function in just _Layout.cshtml or every view page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a browser back action, You could use https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

```
<img src="~Content/icons/btnBack.png" onclick="window.history.back();" />
```

But I suggest that you put specific links to those back buttons and not control the redirect via js. You could simply use the html link tag;

```
<!-- Specify the Action and Controller name in Url.Action function -->

<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="@Url.Action("Index","ControllerName")">
   <img src="~Content/icons/btnBack.png" />
</a>
```

Another option is to use window.location.href and window.location.replace; https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp

```
<img src="~Content/icons/btnBack.png" onclick="goSomewhere();" />

<script>
function goSomewhere(){
   window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
   // window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Jerdine, thanks for your reply. But my window.history.back() function need to redirect me to whatever page I want, not only the previous screen. Any idea?

Comment: Hi JC, I would use the one I suggested; using the html link tag and Url.Action function.

Comment: I added another option, you could use that for js redirect